# I am trying to simplify my code by making a function outside of a while loop but the conditionals I want to put in function have break statements

Tags: python-3.x, function, while-loop

Below is a sample of my code. I am trying to make a function for my 4th conditional statement outside of the while loop, but some of the nested conditionals have a break statement. How can I create the function outside of the loop but still break out of the loop when I need too.

```
current_room = 'security room'
directions = ['north', 'south', 'east', 'west']
all_items = ['Thermal Rifle', 'Blood Wine', 'Protein Bar', 'Bandages', 'Keys', 'Time Grenade', 'Note']    

while True:
    # Print current room
    print('-' * 60)
    print(f'You are in {current_room.title()}')
    print('Inventory:', inventory)

    prompt = 'What is your move:\n$ '
    user_command = input(prompt).lower().strip()
    split_command = user_command.split(' ', 1)

    if user_command == 'quit':
        print()
        print('Exiting game....')
        break
    elif user_command == 'show items':
        print(all_items)
        time.sleep(1)
    elif user_command == 'help':
        menu()
        time.sleep(2)
    # if command direction is in rooms update current room to new room
    elif split_command[0] == 'go':
        # This is code I want to turn into a function outside of the loop
        # but my issue is the two break statements in the code
        if split_command[1] in directions:
            if split_command[1] in rooms[current_room]:
                current_room = rooms[current_room][split_command[1]]
                # if command direction is kahmeetes office congratulate and break out of loop
                if current_room == 'kahmeete\'s office' and len(inventory) == len(all_items):
                    print(f'\nCongratulations! You have collected all items and reached {current_room}!')
                    print('You have successfully defeated Kahmeete and saved the Princess of Time!')
                    break
                elif current_room == 'kahmeete\'s office' and len(inventory) != len(all_items):
                    print(f'\nYou are in {string.capwords(current_room)}')
                    print('\nYou do not have enough items to defeat Kahmeete!')
                    print('Kahmeete used the T.T.A.D. "Time Traveling Alien Device on you!"')
                    print('You are lost in the past and you will never rescue the Princess of Time!')
                    break
            else:
                print('You cannot go that way!')
                time.sleep(1)
```

Here is the basis of the function:

```
def moving_rooms(command, direction, room, current_loc, item, all_item_list):
    if command[1] in direction:
        if command[1] in room[current_loc]:
            current_loc = room[current_loc][command[1]]
            # if command direction is cellar congratulate and break out of loop
            if current_loc == 'kahmeete\'s office' and len(item) == len(all_item_list):
                print(f'\nCongratulations! You have collected all items and reached {string.capwords(current_loc)}!')
                print('You have successfully defeated Kahmeete and saved the Princess of Time!')
                # This is where the break statement would be

            elif current_loc == 'kahmeete\'s office' and len(item) != len(all_item_list):
                print(f'\nYou are in {string.capwords(current_loc)}')
                print('You do not have enough items to defeat Kahmeete!')
                print('Kahmeete used the T.T.A.D. "Time Traveling Alien Device on you!"')
                print('You are lost in the past and you will never rescue the Princess of Time!')
                # This would of been where the break statement was
        else:
            print('You cannot go that way!')
            time.sleep(1)
    else:
        print('Invalid input')
        time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function can return a value that tells the calling code if it should `break` the loop or not.

```
elif split_command[-] == 'go':
    done = handle_go_command(args)
    if done:
        break
```

Now, just `return True` in your function when you wanted to `break`, and `return False` where you want the outer loop to keep going.